# Assigning tuple to an array

Tags: swift, struct, append, tuples

I'm trying to simply append a tuple to an array as per the below code;

```
class Test: UIView {
    let circleRadius: CGFloat = 10
    let mainThemeColor: UIColor = UIColor.green
    struct Properties {
        var properties:  (coordinatesXY: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, group: String, fillingColor: UIColor)
    }

    var circleCollection: [Properties] = []

    func setProperties() {
        circleCollection.append(coordinatesXY: CGPoint(), radius: circleRadius, group: "test", fillingColor: mainThemeColor)
        //Error Extra argument 'radius' in call
    }
}
```

Could anyone write how to resolve the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialise the new property of type `Properties` you are creating:

```
    circleCollection.append(Properties(properties: (coordinatesXY: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: circleRadius, group: "test", fillingColor: mainThemeColor)))
```

Also, the initializer for `CGPoint` has a `x` and `y`.

Consider if you actually want `Properties` to have only 1 property with all its fields using a tuple, or if it would be better to have something like:

```
struct Properties {
        let coordinatesXY: CGPoint
        let radius: CGFloat
        let group: String
        let fillingColor: UIColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array takes instances of `Properties` struct and not tuples.
Try creating a new instance `Properties.init(properties: (coordinatesXY: CGPoint(0,0), radius: circleRadius, group: "test", fillingColor: mainThemeColor))` and then add it to the array

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
func setProperties() {
        let tuple = Properties.init(properties: (coordinatesXY: CGPoint.zero, radius: circleRadius, group: "test", fillingColor: mainThemeColor))
        circleCollection.append(tuple)
    }
```